# Python 3.7 Anaconda: "ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebKitWidgets' from 'PyQt5'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am currently experiencing the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebKitWidgets' from 'PyQt5'` when importing like this:

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
import folium
from folium.plugins import Draw
import numpy as np
import sys
import csv
#import polyline
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLCDNumber, QTextBrowser
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from CalculateSOCtoRange import CalculateRange
```

So as I am not even importing `QtWebKitWidgets`I do not know how to handle this issue. As there are different importants from the stated quetion in "Cannot import QtWebKitWidgets in PyQt5" I could not gain any information from this.
I installed PyQt5 and Python 3.7. I can not seem to find my mistake, hopefully you guys can provide me any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found that already, but could not get it working with the provided help.